# How to setup hierarchies in MS CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, hierarchy, dynamics-crm-4

I need to setup hierarchies in MS CRM 4.0. I've below mentioned four levels of hierarchy.... Sales Agent -> Sales Manager -> Area Sales Manager -> Regional Office. Sales Agent guy is at lowest level of hierarchy and Regional Office is at highest level of hierarchy. Along with setting up these hierarchies, I need to implement data level security, that means.. One "Sales Manager" can see only the agents underneath him/her. One the same route, one "Area Sales Manager" can see only the "Sales Manager" and "Agents" underneath him/her, and one "Regional Office" can see only the "Area Sales Manager", "Sales Manager", "Agents" underneat that office only.

Please help me setting up this hierarchy. Your help would be highly appreciated !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business units can be set up hierarchically, and you can set up your security roles to only allow access to read/write/create, etc. just in the user's business unit and any child business units.

So, you could set up a business unit for each Regional Office, then set up business units for each Area Sales Manager underneath that, and set up an additional layer for each Sales Manager underneath that.

EDIT: In response to your comment below, here's an example of how you'd have to set up a security role to make sure someone with this role would only have access to their own records. [alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/2079/roles.jpg](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/2079/roles.jpg)

Comment: Matt thanks for your answer. But there is a catch, now at most bottom level ("Agents" level), no agent should be able to view other Agent's information. Now given the fact, that all agents would be there in same business unit, they can get access to each other's data.

Comment: What is it that they're not allowed to see? If they should only be able to see records that they own, then that can be set in their security role. If they shouldn't be allowed to see any other user records, that can be set up too.

Comment: Each agent can have their own leads... Now I don't want any Agent  to get access to other Agent's leads.. Also, it's not only Leads.. the agent should not have access to other custom entity records too!!! That means one Agent should not be allowed to see other Agent's record. Please help me out to set this up?

Comment: I edited my post to show you an example of a role set up with access only to their own records.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot Matt. I really appreciate your patience to answer my basic question. Thanks a lot again.